# Pulling data from API masked with UUID string as a key with dart

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try try to pull my Add_ons. it is prepared with data key of a UUID and values of List body. Essentially what I am asking is how I get the values (name, price and type) in add_ons. Structure at the end.

Here is the preparation of the data to be sent to API

```
Map<String, dynamic> extrasJsonPrepare() {
    Map<String, dynamic> addOnBody = {};
    if (extras.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
        addOnBody["${uuid.v4()}"] = {
          "name": "${extras[i].name}",
          "price": extras[i].price,
          "type": "extras"
        };
      }
    }
...........
}
```

Trying to pull the data from the API code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

MealJSON mealFromJson(String str) => MealJSON.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String mealToJson(MealJSON data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MealJSON {
  int code;
  List<MealboxListing> data;

  MealJSON({this.code, this.data});

  MealJSON.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code'];
    data = json['data'] != null
        ? (json['data'] as Iterable)
            .map((data) => MealboxListing.fromJson(data))
            .toList()
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['code'] = this.code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class MealboxListing {
  List<AddOn> addOns;
  bool availability;
  double averageRating;
  String cityLive;
  String deliveryDate;
  String description;
  List<String> imageDetails;
  String kitchenDetails;
  String listingId;
  int numberOfMeals;
  String origin;
  String title;
  double price;
  List<String> preferences;
  List<String> tag;
  List<String> included;

  MealboxListing(
      {this.addOns,
      this.availability,
      this.averageRating,
      this.cityLive,
      this.deliveryDate,
      this.description,
      this.imageDetails,
      this.kitchenDetails,
      this.listingId,
      this.numberOfMeals,
      this.origin,
      this.title,
      this.preferences,
      this.tag,
      this.included,
      this.price});

  MealboxListing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // addOns = json['add_ons'] != null ? new AddOn.fromJson(json[addOns]) : null;
    if (json['add_ons'] != null) {
      addOns = new List<AddOn>();
      json['add_ons'].forEach((v) {
        addOns.add(new AddOn.fromJson(v));
      });
    }

    availability = json['available'];
    averageRating = json['average_rating'];
    cityLive = json['city_live'];
    deliveryDate = json['delivery_on'];
    description = json['description'];
    imageDetails = json['img_url'].cast<String>();
    kitchenDetails = json['kitchen'];
    listingId = json['listing_id'];
    numberOfMeals = json['no_of_meals'];
    origin = json['origin'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price_before_sankara_charges'];
    preferences = json['preferences'].cast<String>();
    tag = json['tags'].cast<String>();
    included = json['whats_included'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.addOns != null) {
      data['add_ons'] = this.addOns.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['available'] = this.availability;
    data['average_rating'] = this.averageRating;
    data['city_live'] = this.cityLive;
    data['delivery_on'] = this.deliveryDate;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['img_url'] = this.imageDetails;
    data['kitchen'] = this.kitchenDetails;
    data['listing_id'] = this.listingId;
    data['no_of_meals'] = this.numberOfMeals;
    data['origin'] = this.origin;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['preferences'] = this.preferences;
    data['tags'] = this.tag;
    data['whats_included'] = this.included;
    data['price_before_sankara_charges'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}

class AddOn {
  String name;
  String type;
  int price;
  // List<uuid> = Uuid();
  // var uuid = Uuid();

  AddOn({
    // this.uuid,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.type,
  });

  AddOn.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // uuid = json['$uuid'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
    type = json['type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    // data['$uuid'] = this.uuid;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Structure of API

```
{
            "add_ons": {
                "681c3755-40a1-4711-9072-c848a2eaeea3": {
                    "name": "hgfhfgh",
                    "price": 9,
                    "type": "drinks"
                },
                "90e2bfe7-f81b-47c1-bb02-0fb227ddfff2": {
                    "name": "gdfgfdg",
                    "price": 9,
                    "type": "extras"
                },
                "b5c78d1c-9ce3-46ce-a168-6358259d4982": {
                    "name": "ghgfhgfh",
                    "price": 9,
                    "type": "sides"
                }
            },
            "available": true,
            "average_rating": 0.0,
            "city_live": "Fredericton",
            "delivery_on": "Tuesday",
            "description": "dsadasds",
            "img_url": [],
            "kitchen": "sadasda",
            "listing_id": "cd78ac9f-0f9c-49eb-8a52-970c2017fee9",
            "no_of_meals": 1,
            "origin": "Canada",
            "preferences": [
                "Gluten Free"
            ],
            "price_before_sankara_charges": 6.0,
            "tags": [],
            "title": "dsadsad",
            "whats_included": []
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding these lines of code

```
var innerMap = json['add_ons'];
    var targetMap = Map<String, AddOn>();
    innerMap.forEach((key, value) {
      targetMap.addAll({key: AddOn.fromJson(value)});
    });
```